# Changing style with code

Tags: c#, xaml, hyperlink

I have a XAML file where I define a style for some content that is a hyperlink. How can I change the style to a different style using code.

Specifically the styled hyperlink on label3..

```
<UserControl x:Class="FHIRCDALoader.Views.SideMenuView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" >
    <Grid>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Margin="2,0,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  >

            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="TxtBlkStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE7840D" />
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="TxtBlkStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value= "Regular" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF4C47FF" />
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="TxtSubCommand" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8,0,0,0" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value= "Regular" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="activeLink" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>

            <Label Content="Start" Name="label1" Style="{StaticResource TxtBlkStyle2}" />

            <Label Name="labelloadfile" Style="{StaticResource TxtSubCommand}">
                <Label.Content>
                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="#" Style="{StaticResource activeLink}" Click="Hyperlink_Load_CDA_File">
                        Load CDA File
                    </Hyperlink>
                </Label.Content>
            </Label>

            <Label Content="Edit" Name="label2" Style="{StaticResource TxtBlkStyle2}"/>
            <Label Name="label3" Style="{StaticResource TxtSubCommand}">
                <Label.Content>
                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="#" Style="{StaticResource activeLink}" Click="Hyperlink_Click_TestPage">
                        Generate New Id
                    </Hyperlink>
                </Label.Content>
            </Label>
            <Label Name="label4" Style="{StaticResource TxtSubCommand}">
                <Label.Content>
                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="#" Style="{StaticResource activeLink}" Click="Hyperlink_Click_TestPage">
                        Generate New SetId
                    </Hyperlink>
                </Label.Content>
            </Label>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should allow you to set the style programmatically:

```
label4.Style = (Style)(this.Resources["ResourceName"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can create another style like so

```
 <Style x:Key="activeLink2" TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
```

then on your back end you can assign change style to the given control

```
label3.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["activeLink2"];
```

Comment: This nearly works, but I lose the style applied directly to the label (in this case by the TxtSubCommand style).

Comment: No success. On closer examination the reason is that (Style)Application.Current.Resources["activeLink2"] is returning null, in fact the Resources collection seems to be empty. Is this because the styles are being defined within the <StackPanel>?

Comment: try using this this.label3.Style = this.Resources["RiskDetailsMedium"] as Style;

Comment: Already tried that with no success. That collection was also empty. SO I moved the styles out of the <StackPanel>. The collection is now populated, so a step closer. Next problem is I now get the following exception : 'Hyperlink' TargetType does not match type of element 'Label'.

Comment: ohhh you have style for hyperlink but you are using label